# How to create a firewall for a jailbroken iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, firewall, jailbreak

Is it possible to create a firewall for a jailbroken iPhone with iOS 6 or iOS 5? I actually want to get all the internet connections on my iPhone and control their connectivity myself.

Comment: Not possible without jailbreaking.

Comment: And how to do it with jailbreak?

Comment: There is a tweak called Firewall iP which monitors outgoing connections (in Cydia).